# How commonly is 풋 used in Korean, and is describing someone's height a common use of it?

Tags: vocabulary, word-choice

How commonly is [풋](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%ED%94%BC%ED%8A%B8) used in Korean? The word is mentioned in "The Most AWESOME WORDLIST You Have Ever Seen", a list of 625 words suggested as starting vocabulary for English speakers learning Korean.

Is it normal to use it to describe someone's height? On page 12 of the word list, a short woman is described as being 5 풋 tall (it's a list of vocabulary, not actual sentences, so I haven't quoted it).

If it's not common to use 풋 to describe people's height, are there other common uses of the word in Korean?

The English language edition of Wiktionary has various translations of the word, but doesn't include the unit of measurement amongst them.

Comment: OK, I just Googled "The Most AWESOME WORDLIST You Have Ever Seen" and I must say... not really.  You can't just have 625 *English* words, translate them to many different languages, and claim to have a good word list.  Because different languages divide meanings in different ways.  And that's especially true for many common words that beginners should learn.  ("풋" is basically a case in point: 풋 meaning "unit of length" will probably not be in the list of, say, 300,000 most common Korean words by usage.  When we have to use American units, we say 피트.  Even if it's just one foot.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not very common in Korea to use foot (feet) as height measurement. They usually use 센티미터 (centimeter) instead of foot. Example, 180센티/180센티미터.

풋 itself has various types of meaning . The most common word "풋" Koreans use is a slang which describes a sound of bursting out laughing or unbearable laughter.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Putri's answer, 풋 can also be a prefix that means immature. Some of examples are:

1. 풋사랑 : 풋 + 사랑(love) puppy love
2. 풋사과: 풋 + 사과(apple) unripe apple
3. 풋내기 : rookie
4. 풋내: idiomatically describes young or immature

Comment: Technically this is called a "prenoun" and it's main usage seems to be "first of the season" and it is used a lot with produce..  But it also means: inexperienced, fresh, green, unripe, etc.  But 풋사과 wouldn't mean "unripe" it would just mean "first apple of the season"...and it is very common.

Comment: @B.Alvn 풋사과 does mean unripe apple. There is another word for "first apple of the year/season": 햇사과. 햇 means "of this year". Some people may use 풋사과 to refer apple if the year as the first apples can be unripe.

Comment: Also 풋- and 햇- are not prenouns. They are 접두사 and, unlike 관형사(prenouns), they can't be used on their own.

Comment: I have bought and eaten produce, including apples, sold as 풋--- and they were perfectly ripe.  So, I have to disagree with you here.  Or is this a Gyeongsangdo thing only?  That is possible.  Also, most books include 풋 as a prenoun, but not 햇 so I'm confused by comment here.  Also, please show a case where a prenoun is "used on it's own" please...I don't believe that is possible, in fact.  But if I am wrong, I'd like to see an example or three...

Comment: @B.Alvn 풋사과 may refer green apples. I guess that is because some unripe apples can also be green and people mix them. 새 and 헌 are 관형사 and we say 새 집 or 헌 책 (note a space after 새 and 헌). But we don't say 풋 사과 or 햇 곡식. Sometimes the boundary between 관형사 and 접두사 is blurry. For example 한 can be both depending on its meaning.

Comment: I'd recommend you to post a new question if you are unsure about 관형사 and 접두사 as our discussion here is becoming out of topic here.

Comment: i understand the difference and i'm telling you how 풋 can be used...as a prenoun..yes, sometimes it is written with no space as a "prefix" too, you can easily find this and other prenouns used either way.  and as I say, a number of authors writing about the languaage list 풋 as a prenoun.   one meaning of 풋 is, in fact, "first of the season" and that is how farmers and vegetable sellers use in here, where I have lived for 8 years.

Comment: since you want to disagree with my "on the ground" experience as well as my very deep study of the language, i think we are done talking here.  but if you google "풋 가과" (with the space) you will see plenty of examples of it used that way...

Comment: and look at it this way:  who the hell is going to sell, or buy, unripe apples or grapes or anything like that...nobody.  unripe apples are worthless and will make you sick.  no one is going to deal in those, come on.  what do you want me to do, take some pictures of signs in stores for you, or are you going to accept that I might just know what I'm talking about here?

Comment: here, I will help you:  just click this:  https://www.google.co.kr/search?q=%22%ED%92%8B+%EC%82%AC%EA%B3%BC%22&gws_rd=cr&ei=ZenLWMizK4bN0AS_67fIDw

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55530/discussion-between-baxang-and-b-alvn).

Comment: I am sorry to interrupt you guys, but I am Korean who has lived in Korea for 32years and I am definitely sure the 풋 is not 관형사 but 접두사. And it does not mean the first apple of the season, even though it is used in that way, meaning that it is total, grammatically wrong as like it happens a lot in other languages.